# PHP APC: cache locked by a process, works only synchronously

Tags: php, fastcgi, apc, fpm

My PHP APC code stopped working after I upgraded to PHP-FPM. The scenario is simple: one php process writes a var to APC memory in a loop and another php process retrieves it asynchronously.

The 1st script (testing sample):

```
for($i=1; $i<1000; $++){
    .........................
    apc_store("mrg_test",$some_var,300); 
    $t = apc_fetch("mrg_test"); 
    echo "Test: $t";
}
```

The second script, runs as another php process from a different file while the 1st process is running:

```
$t = apc_fetch("mrg_test"); 
echo "Test: $t";
```

These scripts have been running on php apache for years, but don't work on PHP-FPM: the second script cannot fetch APC memory **till the 1st script ends**. Only after the 1st script finishes, the second script can read the last value of $t.

Any suggestions how to read APC memory while the originating process is stull running?

Thanks